# How to count elements by date month and year

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, frontend

I have a function that can count the total number of occurences for elements. However, i would like to have a function that can count the elements by date, month or year.

data.js

```
[{
  _id:"1",
  "Name":"John",
  "Booked":"Executive"
  "date": 2023-03-02T18:15:26.723+00:00
   },

   {
  _id:"2",
  "Name":"Peter",
  "Booked":"Economy",
  "date": 2023-03-19T19:15:26.723+00:00
   },

  {
  _id:"3",
  "Name":"Wade",
  "Booked":"Economy",
  "date": 2024-04-19T19:15:26.723+00:00
   },
   {
  _id:"4",
  "Name":"Mary",
  "Booked":"Economy",
  "date": 2024-04-20T19:15:26.723+00:00
   }]
```

countfunction.js

```
      statusCounter(inputs) {
          let counter = 0;
          for (const input of inputs) {
            if (input.Booked === 'Economy') counter += 1;
          }
          return counter;
        }
```

I would like to be able to get a function that can calculate the total occurence of element booked "Economy" by date, month, year. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that you're asking for someone to write code for you based on your  requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setState if you are working with react

```js
import {useState} form "react";

const Component = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  statusCounter(inputs) {
    const filteredByBooked = inputs.filter(input => input.Booked === "Economy");
    setCount(filteredByBooked.length); // will count the number of elements with booked = "Economy"
  }
}
```

If you want to filter by a certain year or by month you can follow a similar approach where instead of using `input.Booked` you go for `input.date`. you will probably have to translate the timestamp into a string and use a Date() object to be able to access the month or year.

```js
  statusCounter(inputs) {
      const filteredByMonth = inputs.filter(input => new Date(input.date.toString()).getMonth() === 3); //months go from 0 to 11, so this is to check for April.
      setCount(filteredByMonth.length)
  }
```

This should return a count based on a certain month (in example: April (or month number 3, since January starts at 0)